# Error Could Not Find Method (View), Place Picker Google Api

Tags: java, android, google-maps

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
get_place = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBuscarLugares);
get_place.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

        Intent intent;
        try {
            intent = builder.build((Activity) getApplicationContext());
            startActivityForResult(intent,PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    });

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
        String address = String.format("Lugar: %s",place.getAddress());
        get_place.setText(address);
    }
}

}
```

Este es mi archivo XML para el botón.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnBuscarLugares"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00bab7"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:text="Buscar Lugares" />
```

Este es el error que me da al ejecutar la aplicación.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method buscarlugares(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnBuscarLugares'

También intenté con este código:

```
public void buscarlugares(View view) {
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();

Intent intent;
try {
    intent = builder.build((Activity) getApplicationContext());
    startActivityForResult(intent,PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
} catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
if (requestCode == PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST){
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Place place = PlacePicker.getPlace(data,this);
        String address = String.format("Lugar: %s",place.getAddress());
        get_place.setText(address);
    }
}

}

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnBuscarLugares"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00bab7"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:text="Buscar Lugares"
android:onClick="buscarlugares"/>
```

Me sigue saliendo el mismo error, ya intenté depurar la aplicación varias veces, no me dice ningún error solo la cierra.
Intenté también poner el cédigo en varias aplicaciones, tengo un MapsActivity.java y me da el mismos error.

Answer (score 1):

Tu actividad carga el layout activity_user.xml a travez de setContentView():

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
```

Asegura que en el layout activity_user.xml se encuentre el boton `btnBuscarLugares`:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/btnBuscarLugares"
...
...
/>
```

Comment: Deja lo pŕuebo, esque como tengo un Drawer Navigator todo lo de activity user lo tengo en content_user y todo me funciona menos esa función, pero deja lo intento, gracias